# Side by side wordclouds in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, word-cloud, beamer

Trying to plot two WordClouds side by side for a Beamer presentation in R Markdown and I'm struggling to work out how to do it. I'm aware you can use `grid.arrange()` if you set the plots as objects but WordClouds cannot be set as object as far as I'm aware.

Many Thanks in Advance
Samuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` from BASE R and do something like below,
I have tested it on RStudio beamer as well, it works:

```
library(wordcloud)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
obj1 <- data.frame(words=c("a","b","c"),
                   freq=c(10,6,2))

obj2 <- data.frame(words=c("a","b","c"),
                   freq=c(15,11,5))

wordcloud(obj1$words, obj1$freq, min.freq =3, 
          scale=c(5, .2), random.order = FALSE, random.color = FALSE, 
          colors= c("red"))

wordcloud(obj2$words, obj2$freq, min.freq =3, 
          scale=c(5, .2), random.order = FALSE, random.color = FALSE, 
          colors= c("green"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a screenshot and use your favourite picture editor

Comment: Truly a last resort

Answer (score 1):

Use `par(mfrow=c(x,y))`
x denotes the splitting into rows and y denotes splitting into columns.
So if you want to display it side by side use `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`
And if you want to display it up and down use `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`